# Visual Studio Code doesnt stop at breakpoints on debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

Am studying C# and using Visual Studio Code. Problem that I currently have is that new installations of VSCode and C# doesnt stop on breakpoint when debugging. Even on fresh "helloWorld"-app it doesnt stop to breakpoint as in the old laptop it works.

OperatingSystem: Win10
VSCode-versions on both:1.44.2
C# SDK on new: 3.1.201
C# SDK on the old: 3.0.100 (have this also tried on the new laptop)
C# for VisualStudio Code (Omnisharp):1.21.18 on both old and the new one

...would really like to use VSCode as its more lightweight that VisualStudio Community that doesnt seem to have this "symptom".

Comment: Also launch.js are both identical except "program"-parameter where on new laptop it refers to netcoreapp3.1 where as on the old one it refers to netcoreapp3.0

Comment: And tasks.json is also identical

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I had 32bit SDK on the old laptop and this new one needed 64bit. When installed 64bit it started to work.